# SOAP Webservice in Quarkus fails with Unknown JAXBContext implementation

Tags: java, soap, quarkus

I have a Quarkus service in which I publish a SOAP service on startup like this:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "/service", portName = "ServicePort")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@ApplicationScoped
public class Astute implements AstuteManager {

  void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
    String url = "http://localhost:9005/";
    Endpoint.publish(url, this);        
}

@WebMethod(operationName = "Retrieve", action = "Retrieve")
@WebResult(name = "response", targetNamespace = "http://some.namepsace")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "RetrieveInfo", targetNamespace = "http://some.namepsace", 
     className = "dto.RetrieveDto")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "RetrieveReply", targetNamespace = "http://some.namespace", 
    className = "dto.RetrieveReplyDto")
public RetrieveReplyDto retrieveClientPortfolio(
    @WebParam(name = "request", targetNamespace = "http://some.namespace") RetrieveInfo request) {
    //do something
}
```

When I hit that endpoint I get:

```
SEVERE [com.sun.xml.int.ws.tra.htt.HttpAdapter] (pool-4-thread-1) Unknown JAXBContext implementation: 
   class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: 
   Unknown JAXBContext implementation: class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.getJAXBFactory(BindingContextFactory.java:192)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:134)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.create(JAXBMessage.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAP11Fault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:424)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:201)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:189)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:411)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:706)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:260)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:98)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:82)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
        at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm thinking it's perhaps a dependency clash, but nothing in my dependency tree stands out.
Is this the correct way to start a SOAP service from Quarkus?

Here are the dependencies in the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jaxb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mssql</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
     <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Quarkus V1.2.0

Comment: Is it in native mode or in JVM mode?

Comment: It's in JVM (dev) mode

Comment: Do you have a dependency on `quarkus-jaxb`?

Comment: I didn't have it, but I added it and still get the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it could be a class loading issues similar to what we have seen in the past with JAXB when some of the classes come from the JDK itself and some from the dependencies.

Could you try:
- upgrading to 1.3.0.Alpha1 (use `quarkus-bom` not `quarkus-universe-bom`) and also upgrade the Quarkus Maven plugin version
- then add the following dependencies to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and see if it solves your issue.

If it doesn't, please create a simple reproducer and create an issue on our GitHub so that we can have a closer look.

Comment: This works, but it seems rather obscure. Was there a way to tell that this was the issue I wonder?